# Muliple heat sources, same object - final temperature reasoning

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, heat-engine

What happens when two or more independent heat sources heat the same object?
For example, where one heat source on its own creates an equilibrium temperature with the object of 35C, and the other creates an equilibrium temperature with the object at 50C - also on its own.

Assume the same object area in all cases; assume a vacuum, assume other constants as unity.

1. What will the equilibrium temperature be with both sources on at the
   same time, and what is the reasoning behind the answer?
2. Does ambient temperature have any effect on this (assume 0K and 25C as separate cases)?

LATER EDIT: I was assuming the heat transfer to be radiant only - not conduction. In practical terms, the heat sources could be infra-red heating lamps. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two infinite reservoirs, one at $T_1$ and the other at $T_2$, right? So suppose your object's a homogenous rod, one end in contact with the $T_1$ reservoir, the other end in contact with the $T_2$ reservoir. Then, forgetting the ambient temperature part, each end will (must) stay at its respective $T_1,T_2$ temp, just by the problem statement itself. And heat will therefore flow through the rod from the hotter to the colder end. The middle of the rod clearly ends up at $(T_1+T_2)/2$ -- what else could it be? And then if you re-apply that reasoning to $1/4,3/4$ way along the rod, etc, you can see the temp along the rod varies linearly.

Introducing an ambient temp, then there's also a $T_0$, i.e., all surfaces not in contact with the $T_1,T_2$ reservoirs are in contact with the $T_0$ "ambient reservoir", so to speak. And now all these surfaces are held at that $T_0$ temp, and heat's flowing every which way. And dealing with these general kinds of boundary conditions typically involves solving the heat equation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation

Comment: Fourier law is not "obvious" as you suggest.

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams Yeah, I suppose not, but my sense was that op doesn't have the prerequisites for a complicated discussion (which I didn't really feel like getting into, anyway:), so I just wrote a short intuitive argument. But feel free to post another answer and discuss it in as much detail as you see fit.

Comment: LATER EDIT: I was assuming the heat transfer to be radiant only - not conduction. In practical terms, the heat sources could be infra-red heating lamps. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: Sorry (again) fo  the confusion - the way this site works is slightly new to me. Even posting seems to work differently than expected. Do you think it would be better for me to repost this question in a clearer way?

Comment: @JohnMurphy I'm not sure how to treat your situation for a radiant heat source. Equilibrium clearly (if you'll excuse the pun:) depends on the object's  absorption (and emission) properties, e.g., a 100% reflective mirrored object will be different than a blackbody.

Answer (score 0):

The most we can say is that the object gets hotter under heating from sources A and B then it would from either A or B individually (assuming no phase changes, chemical reactions, etc.).

It would be nice to simply add the temperatures together to get 35°C + 50°C = 85°C, but the Celsius temperature scale doesn't work that way because it contains an offset.

We can't even superpose the differences from ambient temperature (i.e., at an ambient temperature of 25°C, add 10°C and 25°C to get an increase of 35°C or a final temperature of 60°C) because material properties are temperature dependent and because radiative heat transfer is a strongly nonlinear process that depends on the difference between the fourth powers of the absolute temperatures of an object and its surroundings.

Unfortunately, all you can do is model the heat transfer process with impingement from both sources simultaneously to estimate the equilibrium temperature of the target.

Answer (score -1):

It's surprising that people believe that two heat sources can be combined
to create a higher temperature than either of the individual sources.

It doesn't happen with any heat sources or heated objects. It is not
possible to create objects at a higher temperature by combining gases,
liquids, or radiation without introducing something at a higher temperature
(or in radiation moving an object closer).

But first the question - to which there are two answers reflecting
two different underlying theories.

Needless to say, only one answer is correct.

**The first approach** is based on the theory that in such cases,
the fluxes from different sources must be added.

At the object, let $F_{L}$ be the flux that creates the "35C equilibrium'',
$F_{H}$ the flux that creates the "50C equilibrium'', and $F$$_{both}$
the flux created with both sources on.

In that case we have:

$F_{L}+F_{H}=F_{both}$

As fluxes are proportional to the fourth power of the Absolute / Kelvin
temperature - and as all the constants are equal, and using $T$ as
the corresponding temperatures in all three cases, we have

$T_{L}^{4}+T_{H}^{4}=T_{both}^{4}$ which gives

$(273+35)$$^{4}+(273+50)^{4}=T_{both}^{4}$ giving

$T_{both}=102.5C$ - as the prediction for the flux-add proposition.

(Makes sense in a way - it is higher than either of the sources could
create.)

**An alternative first approach** is the same - but this time
by allowing for the ambient flux - now called F$_{amb}$.

For this case let $F_{pL}$ be the partial 35C flux, $F_{pH}$
be the `partial'' 50C flux etc.

and this time we have (at the object)

$(F_{pL}$$+F_{amb})+(F_{pH}+F_{amb})=(F_{pboth}+F_{amb})$

this still comes out as

$T_{L}^{4}+T_{H}^{4}=T_{both}^{4}$

So the inclusion of ambient temperatures does not alter the logic;
the flux-add proposal gives $T_{L}^{4}+T_{H}^{4}=T_{both}^{4}$ as
the predicted temperature with both sources.

**The second method** is based on the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics
where heat does not transfer from cold to hot objects.

The reasoning here is that the `35C source'' reaches equilibrium
with the object at 35C; and whatever the nature of the source, it
cannot pass heat to the object if that object is at a higher temperature
than 35C.

Therefore when the`50C source' is switched on, the temperature
rises to a level where the 35C source cannot contribute any heat.

It is also important to realise that the`50C source' is now contributing
ALL the heat - not just some of it.

The resultant temperature with both sources on should therefore be
50C; lower intensity sources than the 50C source do not contribute
at all; which is another way of saying that heat always flows from
hot to cold; it cannot flow from cold to hot.

In fact even more `50C sources' don't create a higher temperature
either - they can't.

**Minor sources cannot pass heat to a surface which is already
at a higher temperature than they would develop on their own if they
were the sole source.**

This can be illustrated by a couple of thought experiment paradoxes
as follows:

**Paradox 1**. In the example above, both sources could be physical
objects at a temperature of (say) 58C - one closer than the other.

In this case the hottest object in the system is 58C - so it is not
possible to create a temperature of 58C+ anywhere in the system without
introducing a heat source that is greater than 58C.

**Paradox 2.** Consider the case where a collection of objects
at (say) 40C within an enclosure where the ambient temperature is
25C.

The Flux-add theory tells us that somehow these objects would become
greater than 40C by combining fluxes - reaching (say) 44C.

What happens if we increase the ambient temperature to 40C when everything
is expected to settle at 40C? - where would that extra heat / temperature
go? Or better still, did it ever exist in the first place?

**Conclusion:Radiant fluxes must never be aggregated
under any circumstances - ever.**

It doesn't matter how many objects of (say) 50C are introduced - they
can't be added together, and if there are enough of them, 50C just
becomes the ambient temperature.

There are no examples in the natural world where radiant fluxes combine
/ aggregate or sum - it leads to impossible outcomes.

Further thought on the mechanisms involved convinces most people -
but not all - in spite of there being a complete lack of examples.

Finally, the reasonable next question is - has anyone tried this?

Go HERE: https://cldup.com/WXAtaZ5fDH.pdf

to see my home experiment - the results of which are unequivocal.

NB. The experiment was originally done to disprove the Greenhouse
Effect (which is adding Solar flux to the flux from Greenhouse Gases).

All I ask is that if you run a similar or better experiment in your
lab (not hard); please post the results for all to see - or at least
let me know via the email in the PDF.

(Now that Trump has canceled the war on Climate Deniers, maybe more
people will feel open to admit that the Greenhouse Effect doesn't
exist.)
\end{document}

Comment: Who says the radiation fields are at the temperatures you have assumed? That isn't what the question asks - it subjects the body to two fluxes, which may not be blackbody spectra. These could be due to objects at other temperatures. The equilibrium temperature of the Earth is about 300 K, but it is illuminated by something that is 5800 K. -1 for your final comment, which is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @ProfRob As you know, I will be posting the results of an updated experiment early next week. Why not wait for that? Besides, if fluxes do add as you imply - what are the rules for this addition?